# Resetting row selection in a data table and removing the tab containing that table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app that adds and removes a lot of tabs on certain events. Most of the tabs contain data tables which depend on one another. Each data table has a proxy created. The problem is, that if I reset table selection with a `tableProxy %>% selectRows(NULL)`, and then remove the tab with that table using `removeTab()`, value representing selected row is not reset.

Here is a minimal example. To reproduce, select any row in a table and go to the next tab. For now everything is fine. The index of the selected row is printed. However, if you click on the button, you'll notice that the printed value is still the same even though selection was reset and the tab containing the table does not exist anymore. Any ideas how to fix that?

Package versions: `shiny_1.0.5`, `DT_0.2`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Table",
            dataTableOutput("table")  
        ),
        tabPanel("Button & text", 
            actionButton("button", "Reset selection & remove the tab"),
            textOutput("text")         
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        head(mtcars)
    })

    tableProxy <-  dataTableProxy('table')

    observeEvent(input$button, {
        tableProxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
        removeTab("tabs", "Table")
    })

    observe({
        print(paste("Observer", input$table_rows_selected))
    })

    data <- reactive({
        print(paste("Reactive", input$table_rows_selected))
        input$table_rows_selected
    })

    output$text <- renderText({
        data()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a clean solution for that. One option would be to add an intermediate `reactiveVal` object, and set that to `NULL` when you remove the table. Or in your case you may want to consider `reactiveValues`, and use the name of the table as the name for its elements to store your selected rows, since it sounds like you are spawning a lot of tables dynamically(?).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    tabPanel("Table",
             dataTableOutput("table")  
    ),
    tabPanel("Button & text", 
             actionButton("button", "Reset selection & remove the tab"),
             textOutput("text")         
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    head(mtcars)
  })

  selected_rows <- reactiveVal()

  tableProxy <-  dataTableProxy('table')

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    tableProxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
    selected_rows(NULL)
    removeTab("tabs", "Table")
  })

  observe({
    print(paste("Observer", input$table_rows_selected))
    isolate(selected_rows(input$table_rows_selected))
  })


  data <- reactive({
    print(paste("Reactive", selected_rows()))
    selected_rows()
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This indeed works! I'm wondering if this is a bug or an expected behaviour...